# phpmyadmin - save file to disk

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

when i point my browser to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, instead of showing me its front page, it comes up with save as dialog.

I'm running:
Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) PHP/5.2.0-8+etch13 Server

I've reinstalled both apache2 and php5.
After re-install i don't have httpd.conf file, how can i get it back? Is there a standard file which i can just copy into /etc/apache2?

I did a locate httpd.conf and the only file i got was the empty file i have under /etc/apache2/ which i made.

Comment: Do other PHP files run ok on that server? If you look at the contents of the file has the PHP been executed or is it visible?

Comment: Can you post the output of
curl -I http://localhost/phpmyadmin ?

Comment: tomhaigh:
php had not been executed
phihag:
curl is not a know command on my os (Debian)

Comment: @philag: why -l? It seems to be for FTP servers only.

Comment: Check my reply about the config file, I updated it.

Answer (score 4):

Did you configure the php extension to send an http header?

In httpd.conf:
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

EDIT
The file is not necessarily named `httpd.conf`, that's just the default name.  Try searching for other configuration files in the Apache directory -- the extension probably is `.conf` but it might be something else... 
If you used apt-get on debian to install apache2, try `/etc/apache2/apche2.conf`
/EDIT

Answer (score 3):

I also get this problem when I install ISPconfig. I solved the problem by this tutorial: 
http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-debian-wheezy-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p4

I think the main code is change suphp.conf config.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/suphp.conf
```

comment out the `<FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$"> section and add the line AddType application/x-httpd-suphp .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml` - otherwise all PHP files will be run by SuPHP

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    #<FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    #    SetHandler application/x-httpd-suphp
    #</FilesMatch>
        AddType application/x-httpd-suphp .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
        suPHP_AddHandler application/x-httpd-suphp

    <Directory />
        suPHP_Engine on
    </Directory>

    # By default, disable suPHP for debian packaged web applications as files
    # are owned by root and cannot be executed by suPHP because of min_uid.
    <Directory /usr/share>
        suPHP_Engine off
    </Directory>

# # Use a specific php config file (a dir which contains a php.ini file)
#       suPHP_ConfigPath /etc/php5/cgi/suphp/
# # Tells mod_suphp NOT to handle requests with the type <mime-type>.
#       suPHP_RemoveHandler <mime-type>
</IfModule>
```

Hope I can help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just do not know where that config file is. I don't think apache can run without httpd.conf. Here is how you can find your config:
`$>locate httpd.conf

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

$>vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Once you located it, find where other AddType reside and add
`AddType application/x-httpd-php    .php`

Last thing you need to do is restart your httpd, it depends on install, but doing `apachectl restart` does the trick. You might have to locate it just like you did with httpd.conf file and type in the entire path to the file.

Afterwords, your phpmyadmin should come up.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know anything about this but... does someone knows a way in javascript to download selected files, for example I select through checkboxes 2 files, and then I click on a button in order to download these 2 files choosing the route where i will save the archives